# Item in <iron-list> not updated correctly when data is removed in firebase

Tags: polymer, polymerfire

I was using `<firebase-query>` with `<iron-list>`, and notice whenever data is deleted in firebase, `<iron-list>` does not remove the item correctly (on display). Adding data into firebase seems to work fine with `<iron-list>`.

Comment: Please provide more details. `iron-list` hides elements by adding the `hidden` attribute, so if you are listing a custom component with `:host { display: block; }`, then this is probably the reason it fails to hide (as display is always `block`, i.e. visible). Use inspect element on the deleted list item in order to see if it really gets the `hidden` attribute. If not, then you have a different problem.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer. I managed to solve it below by setting the `hidden` CSS style. On another note, do we really need to set the `display: none` style for `hidden` attributes inside for all custom elements that we defined? Isn't `hidden` a standard attribute?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After inspecting the element on the deleted list, I noticed the final item inside the list did have an `hidden` attribute.

Setting the following CSS style inside the custom element did resolve my issue.

```
<style>
.class[hidden] {
  display: none;
}
</style>
```

Thanks!